# Android Google Map Api V2 OnCameraChangeListener

Tags: android, google-maps

I am doing a project related to android `Google Map Api V2`. If I set `OnCameraChangeListener` on `GoogleMap`. whenever `GoogleMap` calls the `moveCamera`(), the logic in the `CameraChangeListener`() should be executed?

Comment: Are you facing any issue with this?

Comment: I just want to ask out this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your OnCameraChangeListener callback is triggered after you call moveCamera. It may be not called if the call would result in no change, e.g. moving to the same LatLng twice.

Answer (score 0):

As the [OnCameraChangeListener Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener.html) states, the `onCameraChange` method:

> Called after the camera position has changed. During an animation, this listener may not be notified of intermediate camera positions. It is always called for the final position in the animation.

So yest this listener will be invoked on camera position change.